# How to custom the CollapsingToolbarLayout title animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Actually I dont need the title alpha animation while the CollapsingToolbarLayout is closing or opening. Just look like the picture

[image]

I want that when it is closed the title shows on the Toolbar, and wht it is opened it will disappear, I have search google for a day, but still no answer.

Need some help! is't any ways to solve my probleam? Thanks!

**I have removed the animation of title by add `app:titleEnabled="false"` while I don't know how to customer the animation. 
Otherwise, thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

did you try playing with the textAppearance of the collapseToolBar

```
collapsebar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
collapsebar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);
collapsebar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBarPlus1);
collapsebar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBarPlus1);
```

File style.xml content :

        28sp
        @android:color/transparent
        bold

```
<style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>

<style name="ExpandedAppBarPlus1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="CollapsedAppBarPlus1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

the title will be white when bar collapsed (showed)
the title will be transparent when bar expanded  (hided)

hope this was helpfull

good luck !!

Comment: Thanks, but I want to change the title animationg while it is expanding or closing.

Answer (score 0):

Only this command will do if using CollapsingToolbarLayout.

```
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: The method `setExpandedTitleColor` just set the expanded color, not change the animator

Comment: Add your code in the post that you have used, that will help others to help you.